# How does Fabric calculate the Time in App Engagement metric

Tags: twitter-fabric, google-fabric

Does anyone know how Fabric calculates the Time in App per User metric?

We are cross referencing a couple of analytics platforms and trying to compare time in app and session lengths. The numbers from Fabric are consistently around 50% that of other analytics platforms.

Is it possible Fabric is doing more beyond just average? Dropping the top and bottom %'s maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Zubair form Fabric/Firebase here - Time in App per User is a  measure of how long the typical daily active user is active in the app on a specific day. Fabric calculate this ;

Time in App per User = (median session duration * total session count) / active users

You can find out more on how fabric calculate session [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-metrics.html?highlight=per%20user#sessions)